# MBP late 2013 High Sierra unknown partition(ffff...) with suspicious MBR

Tags: terminal, mac, disk-utility, partition, ssd

So I’ve followed a lot of the instructions I was able to find through a lot of similar issues that klanomath has been a mastermind at solving.  I got all the way up to figuring out what my actual partition UUID is.  But I ran into a ‘suspicious MBR at sector 0’ followed by another ‘no space available on device.’  I started following instructions by klanomath for the MBR problem of destroying and recreating the disk0 however now when I try to create the partitions I get something that looks like terminal instructions on properly executing gpt add command.  I’ve looked it over and my parameters appear to be correct so I’m at a lost on what to do here.  Really hope I didn’t mess this up, I’ve got a lot of stuff I really don’t wanna lose on my computer.  Here are some photos of my terminal.

[image: attempting to fix UUID+destroy/create disk0]

Comment: @klanomath please help

Comment: Ok so I realized the error in my ways.  For the command  ‘gpt add....’ i didn’t put ‘/dev/disk0’ at the end of it.  This allowed me to successfully add the 3 partitions that were originally on disk0 as well as have my disk0s2 type name properly changed.  So the command ‘/dev/disk0’ gives me the same results as there was in the beginning(pictures not included for these results) without ffff..and the ‘diskutil verifyDisk disk0’ command came back error free.  Unfortunately with ‘diskutil verifyvolume /dev/disk0s2’ I get back an error that says ‘unrecognized files system.’  Now I really need help.

Comment: Please add your environement: Internet Recovery Mode or external boot volume? You can contact me directly by sending an email to klanomath(at)googlemail.com.